# SharePoint 2010 FormDigest issue: InvalidFormDigest

Tags: sharepoint-server, request-digest

I'm getting weird error with publishing pages and form digest. When publishing page is in Published state __REQUESTDIGEST hidden field value is "InvalidFormDigest". I also have Notes web part on this page. So this invalid digest value doesn't let me and any user to submit comments. I enabled verbose logging for social data and found the following error in logs:

```
argument:<Item  type='Add'><Title>test1</Title><RTEContents>dwd</RTEContents></Item>
,message:The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.
,request:<Item  type='Add'><Title>test1</Title><RTEContents>test</RTEContents></Item>
```

Does anyone know why this might happen and how to troubleshoot __REQUESTDIGEST issues?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have custom code running on the page? if so this may help http://blog.crsw.com/2011/04/23/validateformdigest/

Comment: No, this is completely out of the box site collection based on Publishing Portal template. The thing is that request digest is validated, but it contains "InvalidFormDigest" string which is obviously not valid.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet. I have exact same problem with everything OOB for my publishing site and see InvalidFormDigest on my page. Please let me know if you have found a fix. Thanks.

Comment: We contacted MS Support regarding this issue. They said that one of Windows updates breaks form digest generation. They confirmed that it should be fixed in the next CU - June 2013 or whatever comes next.

Answer (score 1):

Been looking into this problem as well.

Apparently, around the Feb 2013 CU, code was introduced into the FormDigest control that checks whether or not the digest can be included in the output cache. In this case, the page must be published and the UseDefaultCachePolicy is false.

In this instance (Published and UseDefaultCachePolicy == false), it will return InvalidFormDigest.

More digging leads to the fact that any publishing layout inherits from PublishingCacheablePage, which calls PublishingHttpModule.DisableWSSCacheHeaders() when context is set. Since a publishing page layout is inheriting, this call happens for all Publishing Layout pages.

When the module executes DisableWSSCacheHeaders() it sets SPContext.Current.UseDefaultCachePolicy to false.

This happens whether or not you have output cache enabled.

The only way(s) I've found around this are:

1. Create a new FormDigest control that always spits out the actual form digest
2. Disable security validation for the web app
3. Create a control that calls PublishingHttpModule.DontEnableCachingForRequest

Unfortunately, I've not found a "fix" for this, as the code that's running (as of Feb 2013) is "out of the box" and will always set these values for publishing layout pages.

Comment: Do we have any news regarding if this has been resolved? Experiencing similar problems on an SP2

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/04/10/april-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-has-been-released.aspx  which our testing to date suggests it does work round the problem with NOTE BOARD webpart

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. You could perhaps add a brief précis of the relevant part of the blog article (in this case really just a link to the CU). See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: We are on April 2013 CU and unfortunately "InvalidFormDigest" is still reproducible.

Comment: This article saved my day