# Note Board Web Part stopped accepting new messages

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, social-note

Anyone else having issues with Note Board Web Part not accepting new posts after April 2013 CU? On existing pages with Note Board Web Part, posting new message gets stuck to "Waiting...". When creating new page and adding Note Board WP to the page and posting new message, I get error "There was an error processing this request. Please refresh this page."

I can add new note through Tags&Notes --> Note board, and I can also modify/delete existing notes *using the Note Board Web Part*. Only adding new note from Note Board Web Part is not working. If I create new site, it works, it's just this one site collection root site where it's not working (also occurs on new pages in this Pages library). Also if I disable Security Validation for the web application in question, the Note Board Web Part starts working.

CU upgrade itself went smoothly.

I believe this ULS section refers to the error, as the RTEContents contains the string I'm trying to post to Note Board Web Part:

```
04.11.2013 17:29:51.51  w3wp.exe (0x27B8)   0x1414  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.   b4ae2305-aeb1-47b3-9133-271a8f420e5c
04.11.2013 17:29:51.66  w3wp.exe (0x27B8)   0x1414  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    Stack trace: onetutil.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A22A1) at 0x000007FEEF1E22A1 onetutil.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A3461) at 0x000007FEEF1E3461 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000009256) at 0x000007FEE7449256 owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000002B6F0) at 0x000007FEE746B6F0 mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BCD67) at 0x000007FEF972CD67 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000E22D5) at 0x000007FEE8CE22D5 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AF4182) at 0x000007FEEC4D4182 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AA30A7) at 0x000007FEEC4830A7   b4ae2305-aeb1-47b3-9133-271a8f420e5c
04.11.2013 17:29:51.68  w3wp.exe (0x27B8)   0x1414  SharePoint Server   Social Data xppp    Medium  argument:<Item  type='Add'><Title>test</Title><RTEContents>fsdasdfsdfdsf</RTEContents></Item>,message:The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.,request:<Item  type='Add'><Title>test</Title><RTEContents>fsdasdfsdfdsf</RTEContents></Item>    b4ae2305-aeb1-47b3-9133-271a8f420e5c
```

Any ideas how to start troubleshooting this? Why can it suddenly start giving me this error? Any debugging ideas are appreciated I cannot think of anything more to try...I cannot really recreate the site even, as it is site collection root, so what could I try?

**UPDATE1**

Forgot to mention, if I use Fiddler to look at the triggered javascript call (when posting new note board comment), I can indeed see it gets a OOB error page saying: "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.".

**UPDATE2**
This issue was fixed in June 2013 CU.

Comment: It sounds like something is interrupting the javascript call.  Are there any other javascript libraries referenced on the page?  Does it do it on multiple pages?

Comment: There are number of other javascripts (jQuery, datatables, etc.) BUT they're referenced in .master page, and Note Board does work also on other sites with the same .master. However, I did also try reverting .master to site defition without any custom .js references (OOB v4.master), but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Also other people are having this issue: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/04/10/april-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-has-been-released.aspx

Comment: There is also another known issue, not directly related with Note Board Web Part, but with Publishing pages that contain Managed Metadata fields: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/b585265b-1ec7-421f-9730-2079b30fa835

Comment: @Jussi Palo - it should work if you throw it in the Content Editor Web Part.. Good luck and happy pointing. -Jared
[www.jaredmatfess.com](http://www.jaredmatfess.com)

Comment: This issue originated from a bug in Feb 2013 Cumulative Update, and was since fixed in June 2013 CU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following. It describes a bug that appears to be the same, http://jaredmatfess.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/sharepoint-february-2013-cu-cod-breaks-the-rss-viewer-webpart. I got the same behavior you describe after Feb 2013 CU, and this fixes it.

Comment: Just make sure the web part is last on the page. If it's above the broken web parts, it won't fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another post with the same issue. There are some workarounds, although not a final solution, [SharePoint 2010 FormDigest issue: InvalidFormDigest](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65085/sharepoint-2010-formdigest-issue-invalidformdigest).

This is apparently in the February 2013 & April 2013 CUs.

Answer (score 1):

function CustomUpdateFormDigest() {
if(window._spPageContextInfo != null) {
var $v_2 = window._spPageContextInfo;
var $v_3 = $v_2.webServerRelativeUrl;
var $v_4 = window._spFormDigestRefreshInterval;
UpdateFormDigest($v_3, $v_4);
}
}
CustomUpdateFormDigest();

http://jaredmatfess.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/sharepoint-february-2013-cu-cod-breaks-the-rss-viewer-webpart/

Comment: Tried that on .master page and didn't work, will test it on CEWP and report here.